# Return value from Node.js module with asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I wrote a module for my Node.js project which processes some data and is supposed to return the result, like that:

```
var result = require('analyze').analyzeIt(data);
```

The problem is that `analyze.js` depends on an asynchronous function. Basically it looks like this:

```
var analyzeIt = function(data) {
    someEvent.once('fired', function() {
        // lots of code ...
    });
    return result;
};
exports.analyzeIt = analyzeIt;
```

Of course, this cannot work because `result` is still empty when it is returned. But how can I solve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You solve it the same way Node solves it in its API: With a callback, which might be a simple callback, an event callback, or a callback associated with a promise library of some kind. The first two are more Node-like, the promise stuff is very au currant.

Here's the simple callback way:

```
var analyzeIt = function(data, callback) {
    someEvent.once('fired', function() {
        // lots of code ...

        // Done, send result (or of course send an error instead)
        callback(null, result); // By Node API convention (I believe),
                                // the first arg is an error if any,
                                // the second data if no error
    });
};
exports.analyzeIt = analyzeIt;
```

Usage:

```
require('analyze').analyzeIt(data, function(err, result) {
    // ...use err and/or result here
});
```

But as [Kirill points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324651/return-value-from-node-js-module-with-asynchronous-function/28324704?noredirect=1#comment44997340_28324704), you might want to have `analyzeIt` return an [`EventEmitter`](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html) and then emit a `data` event (or whatever event you like, really), or `error` on error:

```
var analyzeIt = function(data) {
    var emitter = new EventEmitter();

    // I assume something asynchronous happens here, so
    someEvent.once('fired', function() {
        // lots of code ...

        // Emit the data event (or error, of course)
        emitter.emit('data', result);
    });

    return emitter;
};
```

Usage:

```
require('analyze').analyzeIt(data)
    .on('error', function(err) {
        // ...use err here...
    })
    .on('data', function(result) {
        // ...use result here...
    });
```

Or, again, some kind of promises library.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't get the callback solution to work, so I fixed it with custom elements with which I have already some experience. I thought I could do without changing the caller syntax but I guess that's not possible. 

I hope Promises will get implemented in Io.js soon, that seems to be a rather elegant way to do it.

Comment: @wortwart: ES6 will have promises, but you can have them today, there are several promise libs out there.